# Are @Input() readonly good practice in Angular?

Tags: angular

Is it considered a good practice to use the keyword `readonly` on  `@Input()` fields in Angular ?

Or are there any drawbacks ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `@Input()` field.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:6:12 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'foo' because it is a read-only property.

6 <app-test [foo]="5"></app-test>
         ~~~
```

You can get around this error by removing

```
"strictInputAccessModifiers": true
```

EDIT: So in conclusion, I would advise against it since `strictInputAccessModifiers` does more than just throwing this particular error for this particular use case of `readonly`. Although I do think there's some merit to blocking the manual assignment of `@Input()` fields.

Comment: I don't get this error, do you know which option triggers this error ? (I have `strictTemplates` enabled)

Comment: You don't get the error when you run `ng build`?

Comment: Oh it's `"strictInputAccessModifiers": true`

Comment: I would say that removing that line is what they call "a bad idea". You're declaring that your attribute is read only, so it should be read only. If you want to set it, don't make it read only. Don't cut the nerves going to your leg when shooting yourself in the foot causes you pain...